# É possível tirar propaganda do Unity ao iniciar os jogos

Tags: unity3d

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como eu faço pra remover a tela de propaganda do Unity quando inicia os jogos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode customizar a *splash screen* caso adquira uma licença do Unity Pro, no momento custando [1.500 USD](https://store.unity3d.com/products/pricing), ou a mensalidade de 75 USD ao mês.

Para alterar a imagem:

> Editor > Editor Reference > Settings Managers > Player Settings

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E altere o valor de *Splash Image*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu, bem mais facil responder do que fica dando negativo!

Comment: @AndersonSeibert Sempre um prazer - a pergunta é válida, e esta é a maneira mais simples de se realizar esta alteração. Existem módulos para construir splash screens mais elaboradas, porém não acho que seja o escopo da sua pergunta.